# ReactJS and Material-UI: Component definition is missing display name

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I'm testing some React app with Material-UI, I have this error:

```
Component definition is missing display name

import React from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import PageBase from '../components/PageBase';

const FormPageError = () => { //HERE'S THE WARNING
return(
  <PageBase title="Formulario con validaciones"
            navigation="Application / Formulario Error">
      <form>
        <TextField
          hintText="Escriba su nombre"
          errorText="Requerido"
        />
      </form>
  </PageBase>
);
};

export default FormPageError;
```

With that error, I'm having this in the console:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

What I have to do? thanks

EDIT: I edited the code thanks to the comments below, but I still getting the same warnings:
[image]

Comment: You didn't close the `TextField` properly with `/>`. Could you check if that fixes it?

Comment: Ah, no, I was removing some TextFields for this post (too much of them), I forgot to close it in this example. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Functional component starts like this: `const FormPageError = () => { // code goes here}` .You used `()` instead

Comment: haha, thanks! Didn't notice it

Comment: It would be helpful to know which component is triggering the problem. Try first returning a div from the FormPageError. If that works, then it's a problem with importing PageBase (how it is exported?) or something within that component. Try having PageBase with only a simple div. If that works, then the problem is with the TextField. Was it imported correctly? Sometimes you get these kind of problems because you need to import things using destructuring as such: `import { PageBase } vs import PageBase`

Comment: I don't get it. The main component is App.js I put there in the return just a div, with the same warning of React.createElement. I did what you said with FormPageError, only returning a div with no other imports, and it was the same.